# Visual Basic - Verifing that an array list contains a value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vba

I am having a bit of trouble with a snippet of code, I am trying to add a item to a dataTable which I succeed in doing, but I noticed that if I tried to add the same element the system would let me, naturally I set off to  create some sort of validation to avoid adding items with a ID that is already in the table.

I honestly don't see a problem with my code, but then again I'm kinda new to this. What I'm trying to do is a for loop that fills an arrayList with the ID of the current items and then checking whenever that ID(obtained from the combo box cmbRol) already exist in the list to avoid duplicates.

Any insight or tip would be very helpful.

This is my code.

```
Private Sub onAsignar(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAsignar.Click

    Dim rol As Integer = cmbRol.SelectedValue
    Dim lstActual As New ArrayList
    Dim rw As Integer

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In gridListaDatos.Rows

        lstActual.Add(gridListaDatos.Item(0, rw).Value)

    Next

    If (lstActual.Contains(rol)) Then

        MessageBox.Show("This ID already exists in the table", "Asignar Rol", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

    Else

        gestorRol.asignarRolUsuario(rol, idUsuario)
        ActualizarTabla()

    End If

  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: try checking for the existence of the element prior to adding it.  If(lstActual.Contains(row) Then MessageBox else do the add.  and place the if statement in the for loop not outside it.  I would also not do a message box because that could be annoying if there are 100's of elements in the list.   you might want to log the duplicates in a file just to make sure that all the data is the same.

Comment: It seems that the lsActual is actually storing the integers when I used  a MsjBox, either there is a problem with the selectedValue or I am not adding each element correctly to the list... either way it doesn't give me much insight.

Comment: MsjBox is showing the same row, for example popping up 3 times (one for each element in the arrayList) but showing only the firs one's value like: 3-3-3

Comment: I think I found the problem using:  
           MessageBox.Show(gridListaDatos.Item(0, rw).Value, "ID", MessageBoxButtons.OK) inside the for loop. The list is adding the same value X times, one for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed this... for some reason (may be the late hour) I assumed that the rw variable would auto increment on its own, which of course isn't the case.

The correct solution was:

Private Sub onAsignar(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAsignar.Click

```
Dim rol As Integer = cmbRol.SelectedValue
Dim lstActual As New ArrayList
Dim rw As Integer = 0

For Each index As DataGridViewRow In gridListaDatos.Rows

    lstActual.Add(gridListaDatos.Item(0, rw).Value)
    MessageBox.Show(gridListaDatos.Item(0, rw).Value, "ID", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

    rw = rw + 1

Next

If (lstActual.Contains(rol)) Then

    MessageBox.Show("Este rol ya pertenece a este usuario", "Asignar Rol", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

Else

    gestorRol.asignarRolUsuario(rol, idUsuario)
    ActualizarTabla()

    End If

End Sub
```